# scrape image and title from https://www.open2study.com/courses using python and beatifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib 

r = urllib.urlopen('https://www.open2study.com/courses').read() 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r) 
links = soup.find('figure').find_all('img', src=True) 

for link in links: 
    txt = open('test.txt' , "w") 
    link = link["src"].split("src=")[-1] 
    download_img = urllib.urlopen('https://www.open2study.com/courses') 
    txt.write(download_img.read()) 
    txt.close()
```

I need to scrape image and title from [this website](https://www.open2study.com/courses).

Comment: So please tell us what have you tried.

Comment: Thanks, but please edit your question and add your code. Here is the edit link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33583979/edit

Comment: Okay, I hope my edit was right. Now let me post an answer.

Comment: There still is no question in the question. What isn't working and why?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a `split` you can grab the `src` directly with `beautifulsoup`

Use this to get the `div` that has the title and image in it

```
for link in soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class" : "courses_adblock_start"}):
```

Then use this to grab the title and image in each div:

```
    link.find("h2",attrs={"class":"adblock_course_title"}).get_text())
    link.find("img", attrs={"class":"image-style-course-logo-subjects-block"}).get("src"))
```

You also open the page every time in the loop which you want to avoid, you only need to open it once and then use it for the loop like so:

```
url = "http://www.open2study.com/courses" 
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

for link in soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class" : "courses_adblock_start"}):
    try:
        print("Title : " + link.find("h2",attrs={"class":"adblock_course_title"}).get_text())
        print("Image : " + link.find("img", attrs={"class":"image-style-course-logo-subjects-block"}).get("src"))
    except:
        print("error")
```

Here is the new output:

```
Title : World Music
Image : https://www.open2study.com/sites/default/files/styles/course_logo_subjects_block/public/Course%20Tile_world_music.jpg?itok=CG6pvXHp
Title : Writing for the Web
Image : https://www.open2study.com/sites/default/files/styles/course_logo_subjects_block/public/3_writing_for_web_C_0.jpg?itok=exQApr-1
```

Comment: I tried your codes but image was sraped incorrectly .This should be the right one https://www.open2study.com/sites/default/files/styles/course_logo_subjects_block/public/Course_TIle_agriculture.jpg?itok=tB9Z_fdZ  . I

Comment: This doesn't work, did you notice some hidden images?

Comment: @KevinGuan Sorry I don't follow the hidden images bit.  I will put a bit of the output in my answer

Comment: By the way, OP is using Python 2. So use `urllib.urlopen`like OP's code instead `urllib.request.urlopen` :)

Comment: Oops now I understand, sorry I will try again

Comment: See my answer, these non-hidden images use `image-style-course-logo-subjects-block` as class's value.

Comment: the image should be scrapped is https://www.open2study.com/sites/default/files/styles/course_logo_subjects_block/public/Course_TIle_agriculture.jpg?itok=tB9Z_fdZ   , not this  https://www.open2study.com/sites/default/files/styles/provider_logo_subjects_block/public/MASSEY%20LOGO_HIGHRES_0.png?itok=Onmb3jg_    The image should be a sibling of <h2>

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer by explicitly specifying the class like:             `link.find("img", attrs={"class":"image-style-course-logo-subjects-block"}).get("src"))`

Comment: @KevinGuan  Working code is always a bonus!  #facepalm

Comment: @dstudeba . I ran your codes and got this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mina/Desktop/imagesrape.py", line 9, in <module>
    titles.append(i.h2.text)
NameError: name 'titles' is not defined

Comment: @dstudeba .Now i got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mina/Desktop/imagesrape.py", line 17, in <module>
    f.write(i[0]+'\n'+i[1]+'\n+')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Okay now my code can works fine. And @dstudeba, I think your code can't works out-of-the-box because of that `urllib.request.urlopen`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

titles = []
images = []

r = urllib.urlopen('https://www.open2study.com/courses').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': "courses_adblock_rollover"}):
    titles.append(i.h2.text)

for i in soup.find_all(
    'img', {
        'class': "image-style-course-logo-subjects-block"}):
    images.append(i.get('src'))

with open('test.txt', "w") as f:
    for i in zip(titles, images):
        f.write(i[0].encode('ascii', 'ignore') +
                '\n'+i[1].encode('ascii', 'ignore') +
                '\n\n')
```